# How to chnage basepath in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. To remove public from the url i have move the public folder files to the root and all saved all files in to laravelfiles Folder .Now i need to change the basepath of application. Can anyone please help where i can change base path of laravel.

With Regards,

Harpartap singh

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to move any files to get rid of the `public` from your URL.

Just add `.htaccess` file in your root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is simple and safe solution.

Comment: this is not a solution. Just send me code where to change base path.

Answer (score 0):

Just change paths to autoload, app files in index.php remove '/..' (screenshot: http://joxi.ru/aD2P66JS9Nl7r3):

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But if You want to move application root folder:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/')
);
```

But for safety I recommend You not to put applications root folder in public accessible directory.
I understand that You want to install it at shared hostings like hostgator and etc. So I done that with moving all root files of laravel to application folder behind public, and changet pathes in index.php like:

```
require __DIR__.'/../app_root/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app_root/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: I have done same thing move root data to a folder name laravelfiles and after this move all public folder data to root and chnage in index.php like this.   require __DIR__.'/laravelfiles /bootstrap/autoload.php';                $app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravelfiles /bootstrap/app.php'; Now what i need to change the base path. BEcuase it taking publichtml/laravelfiles as a base path .